# Android Studio freezes after launching avd

Tags: android, ubuntu

I am new to android app development. I am working on Ubuntu 15.10, which is upgraded from 15.04. I installed android studio when Ubuntu was 15.04. Android Studio worked well for few days and then it started freezing (not crashing) after i launch AVD. AVD is working fine,I am able to open apps on avd, lock and unlock it with almost no lag. But once avd is running, I cannot change code in studio. Studio just stops responding to clicks or keyboard hits. I can only minimize it then. Can't go further few lines of code. Every time I have to reboot Ubuntu and start fresh. I am unable to get where the problem is. With Ubuntu new version or android. I believe I am using latest version of studio since it was downloaded on 10th Dec 2015.

Comment: Check your RAM/processor usage while you are doing this. Maybe its getting full.

Comment: Yes there can be a memory issue too so check that and close irrelevant programs.

Answer (score 1):

try this it might help you

```
start a terminal
chmod +x gradlew
./gradlew
./gradlew build
```

If that does not work try to reinstall your Android Studio that might fix the issue.

Comment: it is showing no such file or directory. 'gradlew'. I am considering that due to ubuntu update this is freezing. before the update things were working fine. I will take back upof current projects and try reinstalling ubuntu and studio with jdk. Hope this will solve. And since I have not installed many applications on ubuntu, it will be done in matter for few hours. Thank you @Shvet Chakra for helping anyway
and vishnu narayanan, yes I checked the memory using "watch -n 5 free -m" but mem is not getting full. I have 4gb RAM but and its showing 1334 free. But, thanks for the suggestion.